# How should I do the classification of images with different orientation?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, image-processing, deep-learning, classification

I have been working on a dataset in which the goal is to determine that which type of orientation is it. It is a classification problem in which for each record(for most of them) I am having 4 images - front facing, left facing, right facing and back facing product images.
I want to classify these images in the above 4 categories.
The dataset looks like this : [image]

I have downloaded the images and put them in different folders according to their classes.

**Methods I have applied:**

Till now I have applied two methods to classify these images.

1) I have tried vgg16 directly to classify the images but it did not give me even 50% accuracy.

2) I converted those images into edge images with black background as:[image]

This is done using canny edge detection. It was done because in the result I was getting images with similar color dresses, similar design dresses, etc.
On top of these I again applied vgg16, resnet50, inception models but nothing seemed to work.

Can you suggest some ideas that can work in my case and classify the images in a better way.

Answer (score 0):

first of all yor data set has to be equally splited. For instance 80% train and 20% test. After that you have to balance these sets (train set 60% of class A images, 40% of class B images) the exact same for test set.

Comment: I created that balance when I started the training, each class has the same percentage of train and test set records. What about after that.

Comment: 1)if one class has small amout of images try to use data augmentation, because your network won't learn these few images.

2)Try bigger filters because as i see from the image above the valueable information is spread across on your image.

3)Use Batch Normalization 

4) Use dropouts on fully conented layers (0.3-0.5 will do the job) 

i had the exact same problem with images but when i used BN and Dropout it is all fixed.

Comment: 1)I might have not mentioned it but I have applied data augmentation for both the solutions.
2)I have used batch normalization and dropouts on top of vgg16 and resnet50.
3) I don't understand what you mean by bigger filters can you please elaborate a bit.

Comment: If it means the kernal size then I am using a predefined architecture only and on top of that I'm not using any convolution operation.